# Mongodb multiple key aggregation by date (from timestamp)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection with millions of records regarding transactions.  I would like to create a query aggregated by date and resolution.

My document look like:

```
{
    "_id": "Dan",
    "finish_date": "2017-01-02 15:23:45.234Z",
    "resolution": "canceled"
}
{
    "_id": "John",
    "finish_date": "2017-01-02 18:54:19.090Z",
    "resolution": "completed"
}
{
    "_id": "Pete",
    "finish_date": "2017-01-02 19:11:27.418Z",
    "order_resolution": "completed"
}
```

I would like the query output to look something like:

```
{
    "2017-01-02" : {
        "canceled": 1,
        "completed": 2,
    }
}
{
    "2017-01-03" : {
        "completed": 5,
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?  Currently, my output looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "curDate" : "2017-01-02",
        "reason" : "canceled"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
    "_id" : {
        "curDate" : "2017-01-02",
        "reason" : "completed"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "curDate" : "2017-01-03",
        "reason" : "completed"
    },
    "count" : 5.0
}
```

The query looks like:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": { 
                "finish_date": { 
                    "$gt": new Date("2017-01-02"), 
                    "$lt": new Date("2017-01-08") 
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                _id : {
                    curDate: {
                        $substr: ["$finish_date", 0, 10]
                    },
                    reason: "$resolution"
                },
                count: { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": { "_id.curDate": 1, "_id.reason": 1 }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: The best you can do is get the following output `{
    "date": "2017-01-02",   "canceled": 1,  "completed": 2 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new operator `$arrayToObject` available in `3.4.4` version with below aggregation query.

`$group` by `curDate` and push the `reason` and `count` values into `reasoncount` array.

`$zip` the `reason` and `count` array values together followed by `$arrayToObject` to create `reason` and `count` structure.

Same logic to create a `curDate` structure while keeping the previous `reason` and `count` structure.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$match:{finish_date:{$gt: new Date("2017-01-02"),$lt: new Date("2017-01-08")}}},
        {$group:{_id:{curDate:{$substr:["$finish_date",0,10]},reason:"$resolution"},count:{$sum: 1}}},
        {$sort:{"_id.curDate":1,"_id.reason":1}},
        {$group:{_id:"$_id.curDate", reasoncount:{$push:{reason:"$_id.reason",count:"$count"}}}},
        {$addFields:{reasoncount: {$arrayToObject:{$zip:{inputs:["$reasoncount.reason", "$reasoncount.count"]}}}}},
        {$group:{_id:null, result:{$push:{curDate:"$_id",reasoncount:"$reasoncount"}}}},
        {$addFields:{result: {$arrayToObject:{$zip:{inputs:["$result.curDate", "$result.reasoncount"]}}}}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you Veeram.  I forgot to mention one fun fact, I'm stuck on version 2.6.1

Comment: Np. You may have to use the client side java script to format the response.